# Authorising multiple devices

Tags: web-services, security

The application will be on multiple devices talking back to a central web service (this does all of the work).

Which is the best of securing the application in the sense that the web service only sends information back to known devices? I am guessing some sort of registered serial number on the web service, but I expect that it can be spoofed pretty easily.

Server framework:

.net 3.5
asp.net web service (implemented through .ashx instead of usual routes, chosen as I want complete flexibility and control over the responses etc)

Target platforms:

1. Windows with 3.5 installed
2. iPhone/iPads
3. Android devices
4. Windows Phone devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to secure the link between your servers and large number of clients is by using SSL.  Your server could be https with a certificate from a CA.  Each individual client could use [client-side certificates](http://www.garex.net/apache/) signed by your server.

However an attacker will always be able to gain access to your API as if he was a device. In that there is no place to keep a secret key on a mobile device.